# Ajax Load function not passing data to controller laravel 5.1

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Jquery Ajax

```
var page = $(this).attr("data-page");

$("#results").load('pagination',{"page":page}, function(){ 

});
```

Route File

```
Route::get('pagination',"MyController@pagination" );
```

Controller

```
public function pagination(){ $name=Input::get("page");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use correctly `{{url("pagination")}}` to get your url and do a general jquery ajax request

Try

```
   $.ajax({url:'{{url("pagination")}}',data:{page:page},success:function(data){
   $("#results").html(data);
}});
```

Comment: Further explanation as to why to try this would be very helpful.

Comment: please acceptthe answer if its answering your question